# rails 4 validate presence of specific domain in email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I need to validate that my `:email` attribute includes a specific attribute - `@kodak.com`.

How can I do that? I am using Rails 4.

Something like:

`validates_inclusion_of :email, '@kodak.com'`

Comment: In Rails 4 you should be using the new [`validates`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates) method and avoid using the obsolete `validates_inclusion_of` type methods. The newer method is much more flexible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this:

```
validates :email, format: { with: /\b[A-Z0-9._%a-z\-]+@kodak\.com\z/,
                  message: "must be a kodak.com account" }
```